# Using SQL Server : how to show data in parent child relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like this:

**Master**

```
Id       MasterName
---------------------
1        Electronic
2        HomeNeeds
```

**Child table**

```
Ch_Id      Ch_Name      Master_Id
-----------------------------------
1          L.G             1
2          Nokia           1
3          WoodLand        2
```

Please help me - how can I display data in parent-child relationship?

Like in Table it should display Like

```
Id   Product
---------------
1    Electronic
  (Within This)
   Lg 
   Nokia
```

I know joins but its will not helpful for me

Comment: Why isn't a `JOIN` useful? That seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: How do you think you'll link parent to child if you don't use `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT
    M.MasterName,
    STRING_AGG (c.ChildName, ', ') as products,
    M.Id
FROM
    Master AS M
    JOIN
    Child as C
    ON M.Id = C.MasterId
GROUP BY
    M.MasterName,
    M.Id
```

Comment: May i  know what is STRING_AGG

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the definition and examples.